# No route matches [POST] "/article/1/like"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook-like, ruby-on-rails-7, fbsdklikebutton

I got an error

No route matches [POST] "/article/1/like"

My articles_controller.rb is.

```
 def like
    @article = article.all.find(params[:id])
    Like.create(user_id: current_user.id, article_id: @article.id)
    redirect_to articles_path(@article)
  end
```

This is my index page.

```
 <% if article.liked?(current_user) %>
                    <%= button_to "like", like_path(article), methode:"put", desabled: true %>
                  <% else %>
                    <%= button_to "like", like_path(article), methode:"put" %>
                  <% end %>
```

and routes.rb is

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'static_pages/landing_page'
  get 'static_pages/dashboard'
  

  devise_for :users
  resources :users


  resources :articles do
    resources :comments
  end


  put '/article/:id/like', to: 'article#like', as: 'like'

  root "articles#index"
end
```

I am writing this code from a website given below.
[enter link description here](https://Rails.application.routes.draw%20do%20%20%20get%20%27static_pages/landing_page%27%20%20%20get%20%27static_pages/dashboard%27%20%20%20%20%20%20%20devise_for%20:users%20%20%20resources%20:users%20%20%20%20%20resources%20:articles%20do%20%20%20%20%20resources%20:comments%20%20%20end%20%20%20%20%20put%20%27/article/:id/like%27,%20to:%20%27article#like%27,%20as:%20%27like%27%20%20%20%20root%20%22articles#index%22%20end)

Comment: ```methode:"put"``` is not a valid attribute, try ```method: :put``` Also your link doesnt work for me.

EDIT: I dont think ```desabled: true``` will work either, try **disabled**

Answer (score 0):

The idomatically correct way to [add additional actions to a resource is](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions):

```
resources :articles do
  put :like
  resources :comments
end
```

This creates the route `/articles/:article_id/like(.:format)` - not that `articles` is plural.

```
<%= button_to "like", article_like_path(article), method: :put, disabled: article.liked?(current_user) %>
```

Comment: It can be debated if this is actually a the most RESTful design. I would use `POST /articles/:id/likes` instead as you're actually creating a resource and not updating.

Comment: shouldn't the correct syntax be `put :like, on: :member` ? (according to the Rails doc cited)

Answer (score 0):

```
    def like
    @article = article.all.find(params[:id])
    Like.create(user_id: current_user.id, article_id: @article.id)
    redirect_to articles_path(@article)
  end
```

in like method use `params[:article_id]` instead of `params[:id]`